# How to prevent child from interfering with parent's stdin after fork()

Tags: c, fork, stdin

I have a program reading from stdin and whilst doing this it sometimes need to fork() and execute a command asynchronously.  Sometimes shortly after this fork (probably whilst the command is running), the parent seems to lose data read from stdin.  If only a single byte is lost, the program will never recover.

The man page for fork() says that the child inherits copies of the parent's set of open file descriptors, but trying close(STDIN_FILENO) just after fork() and before execvp() doesn't help.

My program basically does:

```
if (we_need_to_run_a_command_asynchronously) {
  if (!fork()) {
    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    char *args[] = { "command", "arg", "etc", 0 };
    setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, -19);
    execvp("command", args);
    exit(0);  // Ignore errors
  }
}
```

How can I be sure that the child cannot interfere with the parent's stdin (or anything else belonging to the parent)?  The command executed is typically a shell script.

I don't know exactly what goes wrong in my program, but it runs fine as long as it doesn't run any commands.  Only sometimes (not always) just after it runs a command, the data that it reads from stdin somehow gets corrupted, which is why I suspect that the problem is related to stdin after fork().

Comment: Could you test your hypothesis by writing two small test programs, one that reads from stdin and one that doesn't, and having your parent program execute those and see what happens?

Comment: kindly share a small compilable program . It can help us get into it

Comment: Rather than explicit close's, you could set the close-on-exec flag for the standard input.  However, the problem is just as likely to have a different cause (a short sample program demonstrating the problem can be helpful).

Comment: Perhaps could spawn a pthread instead of a new process?

Comment: Your executed command is entitled to have standard input open.  You could give it `/dev/null` to read from.  What do you know about `command` (apart from the fact that the name `command` is a shell built-in)?  Did you write it?  What does it read from?  Basically, if you connect its standard input to `/dev/null`, you shouldn't see a problem.

Comment: @user1055568: there are two reasons why a pthread is not a good idea.  (1) The command already exists standalone; it would be at least somewhat fiddly to upgrade it to run as a thread, and to upgrade the parent process to run as a thread.  (2) That reduces the isolation between the operations; the two threads would share the same standard input, so any input operation by the 'child thread' would mess up the input of the 'parent thread'.  It doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of closing stdin you could open another file and use [dup2](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) to duplicate the new file descriptor onto stdin.  If you opened `/dev/null` and redirected it to stdin after the `fork` and before and `exec` the child will not interfere with the parent's stdin.

Comment: `/dev/null` is a more conventional choice that `/dev/zero`, and for good reason.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've fixed the problem.  It turned out that in a rarely taken path of my program which also executed the command I had forgot to do anything with stdin in the child after fork().  This code indeed works:

```
int pid = fork();
if (!pid) {
  int fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
  dup2(fd, 0);
  dup2(fd, 1);
  dup2(fd, 2);
  if (fd > 2)
    close(fd);

  execvp(...);
```

So, my mistake, but perhaps my question may still serve as an important reminder that it's usually necessary to do something with stdin/stdout/stderr when forking to execute a command which should run separately from the parent process.  I think the above way is a clean way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting note in the POSIX specification for [`execve()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html)
and the related functions:

> If file descriptor 0, 1, or 2 would otherwise be closed after a successful call to one of the exec family of functions, implementations may open an unspecified file for the file descriptor in the new process image. If a standard utility or a conforming application is executed with file descriptor 0 not open for reading or with file descriptor 1 or 2 not open for writing, the environment in which the utility or application is executed shall be deemed non-conforming, and consequently the utility or application might not behave as described in this standard.

It is interesting to speculate whether your implementation is exercising the 'may' option.  Opening `/dev/null` explicitly as standard input is safest.